# RxJS. Creating an Observable from 2 properties

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, observable, rxjs5

I'm trying to wrap my head around reactive programming and observables.

What is the reactive way to solve the following scenario?

I have an object with 2 properties.

At anytime, one, both or neither of these properties can be set.

Each of these properties dispach events that I can listen to.

Only when both properties are set I want to listen to their update events and run some kind of aggregation on their properties.

Comment: I think a code example of said properties and events should be added to the question to reduce the number of assumptions that would need to be made when answering.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create a stream from each property and then combine the streams using `combineLatest`.

`combineLatest` will not produce a value until both inputs have produced a value. After both inputs have produced a value, the stream will update every time either value changes. See code below:

```
const property1$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button1, 'click');
const property2$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button2, 'click');

const aggregateWhenBothAreClicked$ = property1$
  .combineLatest(property2$)
  .map([property1,property2])=>doStuff(property1,property2))
```

The `doStuff` function will not be called until both buttons have been clicked. Once both buttons have been clicked, the `doStuff` function will be called everytime afterwards.